# Can the header bar alignment be cleaned up in webkit browsers?

Tags: bug, design

Using the current stable channel release of Chrome (27 something), the header bar of the new theme is a little bit katywampus:

[image: Chrome 27 screenshot]

Specifically the vertical alignment of the various text, images and menu controls is inconsistent. The menu drop down icon next to my user name is not aligned the same way as the one on the collider. The badge icons are not lined up on the same mid-line as the counters next to them. Also the entire collider section appears to be on a lower baseline than the right section of the header.

The same thing in a Firefox derivative shows much more consistent vertical alignment:

[image: Iceweasel 20 screenshot]

Edit: The same problem shows up in the Chrome beta channel v28 browser. Not sure about other webkit based browsers yet.

Comment: Any news on this? Seems weird that Christianity has a thicker header bar that all the other sites.